# Preload tiles before animation

Tags: animation, preload, openlayers-3

I am currently doing some animation [(smooth zooming & panning)](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~tmm/courses/cpsc533c-04-spr/readings/zoompan.pdf) in OpenLayers using [ol.animation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/apidoc/ol.animation.html), but sometimes those animations are too fast to show smooth zooming (tiles do not load fast enough) - which is expected behaviour. But animation on my page starts only after viewer reads whole post (~1min), so I thought I could preload tiles that are needed for the animation in this time of inactivity.

Is there possibility to preload tiles of a layers/map? I was thinking some solutions:

- Create another view and simulate the animation behind the first layer
- Create layer/map clone behind visible one, and create animation
  behind in that extra time. And when animation finished, just show the
  pre-load map
- Call some loadTiles function depending on the tiles I want to load,
  but I don't know it that function exists

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier than you think - tile layers have an `preload` option. So if you want to preload e.g. down to zoom level 3, you could construct your layer with

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
  ...
  preload: 3
});
```

Also see http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/apidoc/ol.layer.Tile.html.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the preload parameter (I thought it preload only low-quality tiles). 

Problem is I have implemented smooth zooming & panning from [link](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~tmm/courses/cpsc533c-04-spr/readings/zoompan.pdf), and locations can be few 1000 kilometers away, and these animations I want to pre-load. Unfortunatelly in this case preload property does not work :(

Comment: You are correct - preload will load lower resolution tiles from zoom level 0 down to the zoom level you specify for preload, but only for the visible extent. This won't help for panning, only for zooming.